# How to auto-close vim's initial buffer on file open?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

So I'm using ctrlp and nerdtree. I found it troublesome whenever I enter vim, open a file by ctrlp or nerdtree, my cursor always jump to a newly opened window while the initial empty buffer window is still opened, occupying the screen. Then I always have to do `<C-w>j <C-w>q` -- while I've trained myself to do it with my mechanical memory, I guess there should be some smart ways to auto-close the empty window once any file is firstly opened.

Appreciate all help/tip provided in advance. This is my current [.vimrc](https://github.com/raycheung/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc).

Update:

Thanks @romainl and for NERDTree I've no issue now. I'm checking how to configure `ctrlp` though.

Comment: What commands/mappings do you use to open your files from NERDTree and CtrlP?

Comment: @romainl thanks for helping, right, for NERDTree pressing `<CR>` would replace the initial buffer. I would edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter will open the file in the same window, as @romainl said.

However, another tip: If you want to see only the current window, you can run

```
:only
```

which will hide all but the current split (buffers will be hidden)

I have remapped it to `<leader>o`

```
" maximize current visible window
nnoremap <Leader>o :only<cr>
```